# FreeRTOS can't set isr routine as critical region

Tags: c, embedded, freertos, rtos, nrf52

I am running FreeRTOS on a nrf52840
I have 2 interrupts running and my RTOS crashes if I enter in an interrupt while in another one
To avoid such case I added the critical region functions, I also added debug pins to see time spent in the two irqs

```
void my_irq (void)
{
    BaseType_t xHigherPriorityTaskWoken;
    UBaseType_t uxSavedInterruptStatus;
    uxSavedInterruptStatus = taskENTER_CRITICAL_FROM_ISR();
    d_set_pin();
    xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;
    
    /* some code */
    
    vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR(acq->task.handler, &xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
    
    portYIELD_FROM_ISR( xHigherPriorityTaskWoken );
    
    d_clear_pin();
    taskEXIT_CRITICAL_FROM_ISR(uxSavedInterruptStatus);
}
```

It did not work so I tried disabling interrupts :

```
void my_irq (void)
{
    BaseType_t xHigherPriorityTaskWoken;
    taskDISABLE_INTERRUPTS();
    d_set_pin();
    xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;
    
    /* some code */
    
    vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR(acq->task.handler, &xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);

    portYIELD_FROM_ISR(xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
    
    d_clear_pin();
    taskENABLE_INTERRUPTS();
}
```

But still I get this and it crashes :

[image: logic capture of irq]

Do you have any ideas why my MCU leaves the interrupt routine ?

Comment: You have tagged this [C] when it is clearly C++.  Remove the `extern "C"` or change the tag.  I think the fact that you are using C++ compilation and linkage is largely irrelevant and a distraction, and clarity would be served by removing the `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MCU is built around ARM Cortex-M4F kernel. I'm sorry, you didn't mention this in your question, did you set interrupt priorities correctly, according to this: https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html ?

Also I've found that you can't call FreeRTOS API functions from within critical section in the ISR. See this: https://www.freertos.org/taskENTER_CRITICAL_FROM_ISR_taskEXIT_CRITICAL_FROM_ISR.html

I'm sorry again if you've already checked these moments.

Comment: ADS_irq priority is 2 and BTM_UART_irq priority is 8. But BTM_UART_irq gets nested its confusing

Comment: what is the value of configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY in your FreeRTOSConfig.h?

Comment: Okay I solve the issue, it was that nrf52840 use only 3 bits of NVIC priority so priority 8 equals priority 0. I set BTM_UART prio to 7 and I never saw the crash again. What a tricky issue, thanks !

Comment: please also check configPRIO_BITS config parameter in your FreeRTOSConfig.h - it should have value of 3